# Any ideas how i can use Fortawesome without override the theme css

Tags: css, wordpress, font-awesome

Any ideas how i can use Fortawesome without override the theme css in wordpress?
I tried using boostrap cdn adn upload the folder on server.

Comment: Please elaborate what exactly you wanted to do or trying to do. If you're trying to use fontawesome icons in your website, you can check my answer given below.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the CDN link of fontawesome to your theme's 'functions.php' file. A brief information about this has been given [here](http://youneedfat.com/font-awesome-wordpress-cdn/). You can also use [this](http://wordpress.org/plugins/font-awesome/) plugin to integrate fontawesome icons easily into your blog/site.